# Why does for not output anything where as while outputs things?

Tags: rust

The lower code outputs the needed values but the upper code doesn't output anything? I had the same problem with the lower code but then I added the last } else { and that fixed it. But even with that the for loop refuses to output anything even when the println!() lines are outside of an if statement. Does anyone know why?

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut lower_limit: String = String::new();
    let mut limit: String = String::new();

    println!("Input lower limit.");
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut limit)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let limit: u64 = limit.trim().parse().unwrap();

    println!("Input upper limit.");
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut lower_limit)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let lower_limit: u64 = lower_limit.trim().parse().unwrap();

    let mut o: f64;
    for i in lower_limit..limit {
        o = i as f64;
        if o / 15.0 == (o / 15.0).round() {
            println!("FizzBuzz");
        } else if o / 3.0 == (o / 3.0).round() {
            println!("Fizz");
        } else if o / 5.0 == (o / 5.0).round() {
            println!("Buzz");
        } else {
            println!("{}",i);
        }
    }
}

/*fn main() {
    let mut count: f64 = 1.0;
    let limit: f64 = 100.0;
    while count < (limit + 1.0) {
        if count / 15.0 == (count / 15.0).round() {
            println!("FizzBuzz");
            count += 1.0;
            continue;
        } else if count / 3.0 == (count / 3.0).round() {
            println!("Fizz");
            count += 1.0;
            continue;
        } else if count / 5.0 == (count / 5.0).round() {
            println!("Buzz");
            count += 1.0;
            continue;
        } else {
            println!("{}",count);
            count += 1.0;
        }
    }
}*/
```

Comment: Did you try printing out the values of `limit` and `lower_limit`, to make sure they are the values you are expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your upper limit is your lower limit.

```
    println!("Input lower limit.");
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut limit) // This should say `&mut lower_limit`
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let limit: u64 = limit.trim().parse().unwrap();

    println!("Input upper limit.");
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut lower_limit) // This should say `&mut upper_limit`
        .expect("Failed to read line");
```

A potential way to avoid this is to rename your `limit` variable to `lower_limit`, giving you double the chances of spotting the error.

Comment: I spent so much time testing it and never once tried to put a high number for the lower limit. Thank you.